# Как подключить Maven SNAPSHOT артифакт под Windows

Tags: windows, maven

Имеется артифакт, задеплоенный в https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
Для того, чтобы вот такой код работал в pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bla-bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

я настроил "c:\Documents and Settings\Admin\.m2\.settings.xml"

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>allow-snapshots</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots-repo</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</settings>
```

Под Ubuntu все работает. А под Windows XP - нет.

Причем, сам локальный репозитарий корректно подключен к проекту, ибо когда я удаляю из него какие-нибудь артефакты, проект сразу ругается.

ЧЯДНТ?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Под Windows файл называется settings.xml - **без точки**!
Вопрос решен